# How find and remove DOM element from directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to make my own tag maanger. I use bootstrap typeahead and add directive to this element and listen broadcast on select action.

I can not find a way to remove tag element that had been added previously. I can not do two things: pass my suctom id and find andremove this DOm element even if id is known.

Can you help with that please?

```
mainApp.directive("tagsManager", ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
            console.log("Tags in directive: " + scope.tags);
            scope.$on('tags.new', function(event, tag) {
                console.log("New tag is arrived: " + tag.name);
                var templ = "<div class=\"btn btn-default\" ng-click=\"tagClick($event)\" id=\"tag.name\">tag.name</div>"
                    .replace(/tag.name/, tag.name).replace(/tag.name/, tag.name);
                var el = angular.element(templ);
                el.attr("bind-data", tag);
//                $scope.items = teamSharedObj.teams;
                $compile(el)(scope);
                element.after(el);
            });
            scope.tagClick = function (tag) {
                console.log("Tag: " + tag);
                // TODO find a way to get id of this element and rempve it
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: You should be able to use `$(this).attr("id");` where the `console.log` is to get the id, then simply use `.remove()` to get rid of it once you have the id.

Comment: Might be able to use ... `$(this).remove()`

Comment: Why not just use an `ng-repeat` to display the tags? Then when you remove tag object from array angular will take care of removing from DOM.  Wouldn't need most of the code you have in your directive that way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of the directive you started as it can easily be replaced with `ng-repeat`, and simpler code.

In controller:

```
$scope.tags=[];
$scope.typeAheadOnSelect = function( tag){
    /* perhaps do an ajax update to server here? */
    $scope.tags.push(tag);     
}
/* example of removing from array */
$scope.deleteTag=function(tag){
   /*server update by ajax, then */
   $scope.tags.splice( $scope.tags.indexOf(tag), 1);
}
```

In Markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in tags" ng-click="deleteTag(tag)" id="tag.name">{{tag.name}}</div>
```

Note that the only modifications being made are to the data models, angular will handle adding / removing the DOM elements internally.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't considered this way. I need to show tags horizontally in the input field of type ahead. Can you advise please how I can achieve this by using your method?

Comment: I accept you answer but I will apreciate if you can help me with my intent to show it inside the input field. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356429/how-to-put-item-inside-the-input-field

Comment: `input` doesn't allow children but you would use a change handler to push more tags to the array