# How to put item inside the input field?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a tag manager and would like to show my tags inside the input field.

I understand that this is not possible by standart and I would like to emulate this by css. Unfortunatly I am novice in front-end development and familiar with only basic css properties.

Can you give me a guess how I can do that?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when you have plugins available for that? http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/ and http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: You have to use a plugin for this, You can try Tag-it it ( jQuery based ) http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

Comment: I would like to train my skills and do this on angularejs by keeping my hands off from jquery

Answer (score 0):

A way you can do this is by adding contenteditable property to standard element, like so:

```
<div contenteditable="true">This is an editable div.</div>
```

then you can write in this element and put other elements inside also.

Answer (score 0):

I the below example having input tag with span with some text which is inside input. So like this you can use tag inside input

```
span{
  position:relative;
  left:-35px;
  background:yellow;
  }



<input type="text">
  <span>tags</span>
```